# jQuery + Ajax: submit a single textbox to a controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, model-view-controller, spring

I'm working on a timesheet application. I'd like to add an autosave functionality.
Let's say I have a form like this:

```
<form id="timesheet" action="save_timesheet.html" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="day1taskid2" />
<input type="text" id="day2taskid2" />
<input type="text" id="day3taskid2" />
<input type="text" id="day41taskid2" />
...
</form>
```

If a user inserts a new value (= `onChange`) I'd like to get that specific value and send it to my controller (using JSON/Ajax). For example: I add 2 hours to a specific textbox, and the jQuery ajax should do the update `onChange`. It's pretty hard to find a working example. I've seen a lot of examples using a form, but I'm not submitting the whole form, only one small textbox. There can be over 70 textboxes on one screen, depending on the amount of tasks to show.

What do I need? Could you give me an easy-to-understand example for this case? I'm using Spring 2.x.

**Added the solution ;-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using *jQuery AJAX* for the call to my controller.

### My view:

```
function doUpdate(id, taskid){
        var x = id.value;
        var firstday = document.getElementById('firstweek').value;
        var pid = document.getElementById('projectid').value;

        if (x >=0 && x <= 24 && x != ""){
            $.post("savets.html", { hours: x, id: id.id, taskid: taskid, firstday: firstday, pid: pid }, function(data) {
                alert("callback");  
            });  
        } else {
            alert("Please enter a valid number: 0 - 24");
        }
```

### My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/savets.html" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTimeRecord(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request,
        ) {
    System.out.println("Doing the insert onUpdate with value = "
            + request.getParameter("hours") + " for ID "
            + request.getParameter("id") + " " 
            + request.getParameter("firstday")  + " " 
            + request.getParameter("taskid"));
```

### Form:

```
<input type="text" onChange=doUpdate(id of my record, the taskid) />
```

The rest is selfexplanatory. I have hidden values in my form, I get them using Javascript. After that I call the controller which will execute the update (I did not add this code, as it is a simple check + insert)

Answer (score 3):

You could do a manual ajax post with the content from the textbox you're currently in. Then in your server code handle what ever comes in:

```
$("[input='text']").change(function() { 
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "url/to/your/server",
        data: { name: $this.attr("id"), value: $this.val() },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

This will send a key-value pair to your server with the key being the id of the textbox, and the value would be the actual value.

So in your server code you could just check the key, and handle the value accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. But what about the controller part? I've seen a lot of controllers for Spring MVC 3, but I'm running (have to) an outdated version.

Comment: I think someone else is gonna have to help you there. I'm not very familiar with Spring, unfortunately...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort though. I got that part working yet! I just need to do the controller part (I don't know --how-- to process the values once they get to the controller)

Comment: If you're getting the ajax to call the right controller, I guess you'd have access to the request parameters, right?

Comment: Then you could look for the parameter, right? `(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String value)` Then you'd look for what ever field you need to update to match the `name` parameter, and update it with the `value` parameter. (Updated my answer)

Comment: I figured it out on my own. It was so obvious that I didn't think about it. Thanks a lot for the effort, appreciate it!!

Comment: No problem. Glad you worked it out. Might be a good idea to post the solution here, in case anyone else is having the same problem, then you can just mark your own answer as the right answer (: